# Como posso transformar quebra de linha em <br /> em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, string

No PHP, podemos converter uma quebra de linha para um `<br/>` através da função `nl2br`.

E no JavaScript? Como posso fazer isso de maneira segura?

Decidi fazer a pergunta porque não sei se um simples `replace("\n")` cabe para todos os casos de quebra de linha.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Existe um projeto no GitHub chamado php.js, que se propõe a converter funções do PHP em Javascript. Eles portaram essa função da seguinte maneira:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

Fontes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467840/nl2br-equivalent-in-javascript

http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/

Comment: +1 pelo xhtml ;)

Comment: Eu não tenha nada contra a resposta ter mais votos e ter sido aceita, acho ela boa, mas essa o XHTML não me convence. Pra que fazer isto? Se não é para um humano ler, não faz diferença. Escolha um padrão e use ele sempre. XHTML é obsoleto. Eu coloquei na minha do jeito que o AP colocou na pergunta, mas eu usaria no meu código um `<br>` que é o padrão do HTML 5 e que é aceito por todos navegadores.

Answer (score 10):

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/RegExBreakLine.js).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/221800).

Ou pode usar a [*tag* sem a barra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46370/101).

Comment: Exatamente! Estava preocupada de isso ser mais complexo do que um simples `.replace("\n", '<br/>')`. Valeu :)