# Qual padrão usar: HTML5 ou XHTML5?

Tags: html, html5, xhtml

Por que não devemos misturar os dois e qual dos padrões é mais útil nos dias atuais?

Comment: Sendo o Advogado do Diabo: infelizmente foi escolhido o HTML5 no lugar do XHTML, por uma decisão de popularização (no XHTML você tem que escrever o código certo, HTML5 aceita qualquer porcaria e faz o melhor esforço possível pra interpretar). Como estas decisôes são tomadas por um misto de comitês e um pouco de forças de mercado, e não necessariamente por um grupo com profundidade técnica e experiência prática, o HTML e CSS são o que são hoje, onde você tem todos os recursos do mundo, mas está sempre tendo que fazer o maior "baile" pra conseguir fazer as coisas básicas funcionarem logicamente.

Comment: @Bacco Legal sua colocação... mas o que você entende por diferença entre escrever código certo no XHTML e qualquer porcaria no HTML5? Não é possível escrever código certo em ambos, com nível de qualidade técnica nos dois? Obrigada!

Comment: No XHTML, pela especificação original, se as tags não abrirem e fecharem certo, por exemplo, é para o browser dar erro, e nem mostrar. SImplesmente vai aparecer que o documento não pode ser exibido por estar mal-formado. No HTML vale o conceito do "interprete da maneira que conseguir", caso a estrutura esteja errada. Isso faz com que muitos desenvolvedores simplesmente vejam na tela, e se "parecer bom", publicam como está. E muitas vezes, vai pro ar com problemas mesmo.

Comment: Entendi esse seu exemplo. Em uma das respostas abaixo também foi mencionado. Mas consegue citar alguns outros motivos, fora esse? Obrigada!

Comment: Se eu achar algum artigo, mando link. Esse debate já "esfriou" faz alguns anos, na verdade. Na época estava acalorado o assunto, mas quem ganhou a "queda de braço" foi o HTML5.

Comment: Essa conversa me lembrou da vontade de ter uma caneca dessas: [CSS is awesome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qL8yH.jpg)! kkk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XHTML está abandonado, todas versões. As antigas ainda são suportadas pelos navegadores. A versão 5, até onde eu sei não é suportada por nenhum e não será, exceto pelas coisas que batem com HTML5. O caminho é o HTML5.

Particularmente considero um erro, ainda que permitido, usar qualquer elemento de XHTML, por exemplo, o [*trailling slash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46370/101).

[Resposta no Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149843/389).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bem lembrado do trailing slash. Ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginam, no HTML5 o trailing slash NÃO fecha a tag. É simplesmente ignorado.

Comment: Usando elementos do XHTML, como o trailing slash, eu tenho alguma vantagem (exemplo: a retrocompatibilidade)? Ou ele não foi bem aceito nem em seu auge?

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira retrocompatibilidade com o que exatamente? Não é bem elementos XHTML dentro de HTML5 (apesar de haver sim, como SVGs ou outros), mas creio que o AR fala do uso trailing slash em tags "VOID" (acho que é este o nome)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tipo `<br />` ou `<hr />` (foi isso que entendi com a resposta dele)? Penso que talvez exista uma melhor compatibilidade com navegadores antigos, da mesma forma que usamos recursos como o [`babel.js`](https://babeljs.io/) pra melhorar a compatibilidade do código JavaScript

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46370/101

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira trailling slash era suportado em HTML4.01, mas a ausencia disto em XHTML não, no entanto não vejo com alguém poderia querer usar um Firefox3 por exemplo, quase nada usado hoje funciona em navegadores antigos, eu tenho um FW front que dá suporte com fallbacks básicos para IE8 e Android2.3 (browser nativo) e só, de resto, tipo um IE6 ou 7 nem faz mais sentido discutir, outra coisa, fora o XML+XHTML, tinha nos browsers os DOCTYPES, mas mesmo assim se me recordo os traillings não afetavam

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira Só pra constar, quando o AR fala de XHTML fala de `HTML eXtendido` e não de `XML+HTML`, a presença de XML em XHTML é parte disto, mas um XHML pode não conter nenhum XML... só as tags VOID (br, hr, input, etc) que precisariam do trailling, mas em HTML5 isto se tornou opcional, e o DOCTYPE em navegadores antigos não é suportado, logo o navegador entraria em QuirksMode ou StandarMode, leia sobre isto em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209593/3635

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 é a mais recente evolução do padrão que define o HTML. É uma nova versão da linguagem HTML, com novos elementos, atributos, e comportamentos. Uma vez que ela se tornou padrão é hora de todo desenvolvedor web migrar para ela, até porque ao meu ver ela é mais limpa e flexível.