# Qual é a função da meta tag "X-UA-Compatible" dentro do HTML?

Tags: html, html-meta-tag

Poderiam me informar qual é a função dessa *meta tag* dentro de um documento HTML?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Esta meta-tag é exclusiva para *Internet Explorer* ([introduzido no IE8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc817570.aspx)), ela pode configurar a página para ser renderizada como em outra versão do Internet Explorer.

Para entender como funciona devemos começar pelos DOCTYPEs, por exemplo o DOCTYPE do HTML5 é suportado no *Internet Explorer 11*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Mas se usa-lo nas versões 9 ou 10 do navegador, irá renderizar a página com o modo *Quirks Mode*, esse modo faz a página ser renderizada como uma versão mais antiga do *Internet Explorer*, o que pode fazer teu site falhar, então ao usar `X-UA-Compatible` com o valor `IE=edge` ele vai forçar o navegador renderizar com o modo mais recente do navegador atual.

Existem outros modos além do modo `IE=edge` e você também pode usa-los separados por vírgula na meta-tag. Os valores suportados são:

| Valor `X-UA-Compatible` | Modo documento |
| --- | --- |
| `IE=5` | Renderizará como *Quirks Mode* |
| `IE=7` | Renderizará como *Internet Explorer 7* |
| `IE=8` | Renderizará como *Internet Explorer 8* |
| `IE=9` | Renderizará como *Internet Explorer 9* |
| `IE=10` | Renderizará como *Internet Explorer 10* |
| `IE=11` | Renderizará como *Internet Explorer 11* |
| `IE=edge` | Renderizará com o modo mais alto suportado pelo navegador, Se o usuário estiver usando o *Internet Explorer 10* ele vai forçar renderizar como *Internet Explorer 10*, mesmo que esteja com um DOCTYPE não suportado |
| `IE=EmulateIE7` | Se o DOCTYPE definido for valido/reconhecido ele renderiza como IE7, caso contrário renderiza como *Quirks Mode* |
| `IE=EmulateIE8` | Se o DOCTYPE definido for valido/reconhecido ele renderiza como IE8, caso contrário renderiza como *Quirks Mode* |
| `IE=EmulateIE9` | Se o DOCTYPE definido for valido/reconhecido ele renderiza como IE9, caso contrário renderiza como *Quirks Mode* |
| `IE=EmulateIE10` | Se o DOCTYPE definido for valido/reconhecido ele renderiza como IE10, caso contrário renderiza como *Quirks Mode* |
| `IE=EmulateIE11` | Se o DOCTYPE definido for valido/reconhecido ele renderiza como IE11, caso contrário renderiza como *Quirks Mode* |
| `chrome=1` | Forçava o navegador usar o *Google Chrome Frame* (se instalado), que foi um plugin que permitia janelas (ou abas) especificas do Internet Explorer rodarem com Google Chrome ([descontinuado em 2014](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/#google-chrome-frame-was-an-open-source-plug-in-that-seamlessly-brought-google-chromes-open-web-technologies-and-speedy-javascript-engine-to-internet-explorer)) |

O `X-UA-Compatible` também pode ser definido nas headers da resposta HTTP do seu servidor:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Jul 2023 18:55:05 GMT
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Em XML e XHTML o modo de renderização também pode ser alterado usando a tag, exemplo:

```xml
<?x-ua-compatible content="IE=Edge"?>
```

> Notas:
>
> - A partir do IE11 o `X-UA-Compatible` é considerado obsoleto, pois DOCTYPE HTML5 é suportado (não quer dizer que todas tags sejam suportadas.
> - Nenhuma versão do *Microsoft Edge* suporta o `X-UA-Compatible`, portanto não tem como forçar os modos do *Internet Explorer* no navegador, mantê-lo em suas páginas não afetará o comportamento.

### O que são DOCTYPE?

O DOCTYPE que significa **DOC**ument **TYPE** (tipo de documento) e é uma declaração que deve ir no começo do documento sem que haja nenhum tipo de espaço antes (pode até eventualmente funcionar em alguns navegadores com espaços antes, mas no geral não deve haver espaçamentos), ele define o tipo de documento e não é usado apenas por HTML, alguns tipos de XML como SVG também o usam, mas como estamos falando de HTML vou apenas citar os exemplos que foram mais usados e conhecidos.

> **Nota:** se a página não tiver nenhum DOCTYPE, sendo para HTML4 ou 5 ela vai renderizar como *Quirks Mode* ou *Standard Mode* (é semelhante ao *Quirks Mode*, mas é especifico para Firefox e outros navegadores que usam o motor Gecko)

Até alguns anos atrás usávamos o HTML4.01, não quer dizer que porque hoje temos o 5, que ele não funciona, ele o 4.01 é totalmente funcional e não há problema algum em usar, o mitos da internet vão dizer que HTML5 é melhor para o buscadores de internet indexarem o seu site, mas isso não passa de mito, os buscadores se preocupam com outros fatores, como performance da página, qualidade do conteúdo e e até backlinks, mas não vou entrar em detalhes porque não faz parte do assunto.

Falando sobre o HTML4.01, ele tinha 4 tipos de DOCTYPE que visavam melhorar a renderização para o tipo de necessidade:

## DTD HTML strict

É usado para forçar o documento ser o mais correto/estrito, forçando a página a evitar vários atributos e tags, ou seja era bem menos permissivo, mas isso na verdade era uma grande vantagem, se você conseguir criar um site que valide 100% (ou perto disto) com ele, então você poderia ter certeza de que seu site ao menos em questão de HTML seria bem renderizado em diversos navegadores, claro que tudo pode ter uma exceção, mas ainda sim este era o propósito, eu pessoalmente devo dizer que este é o meu DOCTYPE preferido até hoje

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

## DTD HTML Transitional

Talvez fosse o mais comum talvez do HTML4.01, ele inclui tanto os elementos estruturais com os elementos de apresentação, ele era mais permissivo para ajudar a manter compatibilidade entre navegadores e versões

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

## DTD HTML Frameset

É usado para quando se trabalha com frames (não iframes), aonde será necessário a tag `<frame>` (e `<frameset>`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Os frames eram um conjuntos de páginas que eram carregadas cada uma em seu quadro, um exemplo retirado do https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Exemplo de Iframe</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%">
  <FRAMESET rows="100, 200">
      <FRAME src="contents_of_frame1.html">
      <FRAME src="contents_of_frame2.gif">
  </FRAMESET>
  <FRAME src="contents_of_frame3.html">
  <NOFRAMES>
      Seu navegador não suporta frames
  </NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

## XHTML

Além do HTML4.01 existia o XHTML1.0, o XHTML suportava mesclagem de HTML e XML, os HTMLs são poderiam ter falhas nas tags (o que hoje ainda é um pouco comum ocorre por falha de desenvolvedores web) e as tags como `<br>` e `<input>` sempre deveriam ter `/>`, assim:

```html
<input type="text" name="exemplo" value="" />
<br />
```

O XHTML1.0 tinha os mesmos DOCTYPEs do HTML4.01, no entanto mudavam um pouco:

- DTD XHTML Strict

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  ```
- DTD XHTML Transitional

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  ```
- DTD XHTML Frameset

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
  ```

> **Nota:** A quebra de linha na verdade é opcional, creio que as pessoas faziam isto apenas para facilitar a "legibilidade" do código

## HTML5

Com a chegada do HTML5 passamos a ter um DOCTYPE único, o `<!DOCTYPE html>`, que não precisa diferenciar entre HTML e XHTML, aceitando tags que terminem assim `<img src="">` ou assim `<img src="" />`. Também passou suportar a inclusão de qualquer tag, ela sendo uma tag valida ou não e de XML (que geralmente as tags são customizadas por quem criou o XML), um exemplo de XML é o SVG (imagem vetorial):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Olá mundo!</p>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

No entanto não é porque navegadores modernos começaram a implementar o HTML5 que significa que navegadores mais antigos como o muito usado na época IE8, 9 e 10 iriam suportar sozinho esta DOCTYPE, então a solução encontrada foi usar o `X-UA-Compatible`, claro que não quer dizer que tags HTML5 iriam funcionar, isto só impedia do navegador ir para o modo `IE=5` (*Quirks Mode*), para que o IE suporta-se tags como `<section>`, `<footer>` e `<nav>` era necessário algumas coisas extras que eram uma combinação de JavaScript com CSS, um exemplo básico seria isto:

```html
<head>
<style>
section, footer, nav {
   display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
var tags = [ "section", "footer", "nav" ];
for (var i = 0, j = tags.length; i < j; i++) {
    document.createElement(tags[i]);
}
</script>
...
```

O [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) fazia com que o Internet Explorer passasse a reconhecer inicialmente invalidas e assim era possível aplicar o CSS, não quer dizer que uma tag mais avançada como `<progress>` iria funcionar, a tag funcionava apenas como uma tag *inline* (que poderia ser customizada via CSS).

Com o tempo veio técnicas mais confiáveis como [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), basta adicionar em sua página assim (dentro da tag `<head>`):

```html
<head>
...
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
...
</head>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: +1 Eu não conseguiria explicar melhor

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado, fico muito feliz ainda mais vindo de uma pessoa que admiro. Acredite se quiser ainda tinha coisa que eu poderia adicionar como a questão do `height=100%` automático e a questão do `px` opcional no transitional, HTML4 foi uma época de sofrimento xD

Comment: Quando a resposta vira uma aula.