# É necessário usar tag meta em todas as páginas de um site?

Tags: html

criei um site multipage. E minha dúvida é a seguinte: **É necessário colocar as tags < meta > em todas as páginas do site?**
(Biografia, contatos, etc...)

Estou usando no meu site (principalmente na index) as tags:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<meta name=“title" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
```

Além dessas tags, para mecanismo de busca, ou outra coisa importante, **é necessário colocar mais alguma tag?** Pois eu vi em alguns sites a seguinte tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

O que seria isto? Pra que serve? É necessário colocar?
Tem esta tag também em alguns códigos que vi.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">
```

E eu já coloquei o lang:pt-br dentro da tag HTML.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: https://www.seomarketing.com.br/meta-tags-google.php

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/html-meta-tags-entendendo-o-uso-de-meta-tags/30328

Comment: Depende do que você quer com elas. Cada tag tem sua finalidade. Se puder [edit] a postagem e explicar o objetivo a ser atingido, talvez seja possível alguma resposta válida.

Answer (score -2):

É o seguinte você utiliza o que quiser no seu site, agora se é necessário utilizar em todos os ficheiros? sim, é necessário mas não é obrigatório vou dar um exemplo a `<meta charset="utf-8">` é para o tipo de caracteres que vai utilizar se nao colocar isso a pagina nao vai reconhecer certos carateres.

Clique no link para ver a resposta a sua pergunta da meta
[`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209593/qual-%C3%A9-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-meta-tag-x-ua-compatible-dentro-do-html)