# Existe alguma tag que faça o internet explorer funcionar como os outros navegadores?

Tags: html, html5

Existe alguma tag que faça o internet explorer funcionar como os outros navegadores? Como o display grid e outras coisas.

Comment: Que faça mágica, basicamente, não. O suporte a essas tecnologias depende exclusivamente da equipe de desenvolvimento do navegador, se eles não implementam, não há o que fazer. E também não uma solução genérica para todos os problemas, cada qual demanda uma solução. O CSS Grid possui suporte parcial no IE11 com o prefixo `-ms-`. Se isso não for suficiente, provavelmente precisará de um outro CSS como *fallback* para evitar que o *layout* fique quebrado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma tag específica não existe até onde eu sei. Mas existem maneiras para vc contornar isso.

Um exemplo é o uso da tag `@supports`, com ele vc pode fazer um fallback caso o browser não suporte o Grid. como no Exemplo abaixo. [Link da documentação Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

```
@supports (display: grid) {
  div {
    display: grid;
  }
}
@supports not (display: grid) {
  div {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Outra forma é usando o **Modernizr** por exemplo https://modernizr.com/ com ele vc pode criar um "pack" de regras que vão ativar o CSS de acordo com a versão do Browser do usuário.

Aqui tem um exemplo básico

```
  if (Modernizr.NovaFeature) {
    carregaNovaFeature();
  } else {
    carregaCssAntigo();
  }
```

Tirando isso eu diria que seria uma boa prática incluir na `<head>` da página essa tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Ela fala para as versões mais antigas do IE que elas devem se comportar como o Edge. Vc pode ler mais sobre isso nessa pergunta [Qual é a função da meta tag X-UA-Compatible dentro do HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209593/qual-%C3%A9-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-meta-tag-x-ua-compatible-dentro-do-html)

***OBS:* Mas nada disso garante que vc vai conseguir fazer o Grid rodar em versões do IE que não deem suporte ao Grid por exemplo!**