# Para que servem as metas http-equiv="Pragma" e http-equiv="Cache-Control"?

Tags: html, html5, html-meta-tag, w3c-validador

Estou utilizando o validador da W3C em um projeto antigo e ele identificou alguns erros nas seguintes metas:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache, no-store">
```

Qual a funcionalidade real delas? Ainda são utilizadas?

Comment: Sobre a `X-UA-Compatible` a resposta está aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209593/qual-%C3%A9-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-meta-tag-x-ua-compatible-dentro-do-html/209599#209599

Comment: mas gente, não to perguntando da X-UA-Compatible...

Comment: @NetinhoSantos , além da X-UA, como mencionei acima, ainda existem outras duas tags que não são mencionadas na outra resposta... Não entendi seu voto de Duplicada

Comment: tá escrito no título da pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sobre o Erro**

O erro é porque esses valores para a `meta http-equiv` estão obsoletos. Por isso não são válidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja aqui quais são atributos são válidos segundo a documentação atual da **W3C** https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#element-attrdef-meta-http-equiv

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives

Sobre o que é o `Cache-Control`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Utilizando_meta_tags#Cache-Control

> A diretiva "`cache-control:no-cache`" tem a mesma função de "`pragma:no-cache`". O ideal quando se usa essa instrução é utilizar ambas as formas caso não se saiba se o servidor é ou não compatível com o HTTP 1.1.

Sobre o `Pragma_no-cache`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Utilizando_meta_tags#Pragma_no-cache

> Faz com que o navegador não armazene a página em cache. Diferencia-se de "`cache-control:no-cache`" pelo fato de ser reconhecida por todas as versões do HTTP.

---

Sobre o Cache de HTTP recomendo esse artigo da Google https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

*"A recuperação de algo pela rede é lenta e dispendiosa. Respostas grandes exigem várias idas e voltas entre o cliente e o servidor, o que retarda sua disponibilidade e processamento pelo navegador, além de gerar custos de dados para o visitante. Como resultado, a capacidade de armazenar em cache e reusar recursos previamente recuperados é um aspecto crítico da otimização do desempenho.*

*A boa notícia é que todo navegador é fornecido com uma implementação de um cache de HTTP. Tudo que você tem que fazer é garantir que cada resposta de servidor forneça as diretivas de cabeçalho HTTP corretas para instruir o navegador sobre quando e por quanto tempo ele pode armazenar a resposta em cache."*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Continua aqui: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: Uma dúvida que fico é que a diretiva se divide em requisições e respostas, `must-revalidate` por exemplo, é utilizado em respostas, por sua vez `max-age`nas requisições, sendo assim, elas pode se combinar, não entendi bem a questão de quando usar o que em que situação, kkkk

Comment: @MagicHat eu tbm não saberia te afirmar  com precisão  técnica sobre esses ateibutos, só pesquisando mesmo, mas esses atributos que vc mencionou estão na resposta do Maniero, as vezes ele sabe te responder...

Answer (score 7):

Sempre que vemos *pragma* em coisas técnicas significa que ali terá algo que é dependente de implementação, ou seja, cada implementador da tecnologia especificada pode usar aquilo como quiser e colocar o que quiser. No HTML o mais comum é encontrar como um modo de compatibilidade do controle de cache para versão antes do HTTP 1.1. Isto [pode ser visto na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma). Na prática você dificilmente terá problemas se não usá-lo, ou se tiver terá outros bem mais sérios para o uso que todos fazem hoje em dia.

Justamente o [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) é usado desde o 1.1 e como o nome já diz provê diretivas específicas para controlar o cache daquela página:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>
Cache-Control: max-stale[=<seconds>]
Cache-Control: min-fresh=<seconds>
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-transform
Cache-Control: only-if-cached
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-transform
Cache-Control: public
Cache-Control: private
Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>
Cache-Control: s-maxage=<seconds>
Cache-Control: immutable 
Cache-Control: stale-while-revalidate=<seconds>
Cache-Control: stale-if-error=<seconds>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).