# Onde colocar o <!DOCTYPE> legado?

Tags: html

Eu li o artigo na [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#doctype-legacy-string) comentando sobre o `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` antigo que era utilizado antes da versão curta `<!DOCTYPE html>`, no qual não é mais recomendado (exceto ao usar geradores de HTML que não podem gerar marcação com a versão curta). Eles mencionam que este DOCTYPE deve ser inserido na posição definida acima:

> For the purposes of HTML generators that cannot output HTML markup with the short DOCTYPE "", a DOCTYPE legacy string may be inserted into the DOCTYPE (in the position defined above). This string must consist of:....

<sup>Ou em português:</sup>

> Para fins de geradores de HTML que não podem produzir marcação HTML com o DOCTYPE curto "", uma string legada DOCTYPE pode ser inserida no DOCTYPE (na posição definida acima). Esta string deve consistir em:...

Atualmente os navegadores com ou sem o DOCTYPE mais recente já vão saber como renderizar a página, porém não ficou tão claro para mim, vamos supor que eu queira utilizar a versão legada na hipótese de uso válido que foi mencionado, o que seria essa "posição definida acima":

- Acima do `<!DOCTYPE html>`?
- Ou removendo o `<!DOCTYPE html>` e colocando a versão legada?

Comment: Caso a pergunta continuar aberta, amanhã deixo uma resposta esclarecendo e explicando todos os conceitos equivocados aqui formulados. Isso porque essa pergunta não se trata apenas colocar, não colocar, quando colocar e de onde colocar o doctype, é preciso esclarecer a diferença entre artigos e recomendações, o que é o doctype, qual a finalidade do doctype e como o uso doctype afeta o modo de funcionamento do navegador, para ai então refletir sobre que a recomendação diz acerca do doctype. PS: Acho que uma boa resposta pode agregar valor pergunta.

Comment: Só pode ter um doctype por página, ou você usa um ou usa o outro e não tem haver com era usado antes, `about:legacy-compat` não era o antigo, o DOCTYPE é para mudar o comportamento para que se comporte como certos doctypes antigos (melhor explicado em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209599/3635). Esse doctype `about:legacy-compat` só deve ser usado se você necessitar do comportamento legado, se o site que estiver desenvolvendo for novo, não tem sentido usa-lo. Um dos motivos para usa-lo se eu não me engano é devido a alguns sites que usam  XSLT, se não é o seu caso não use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hoje o normal é isso:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

### A exceção:

Caso você esteja utilizando um programa editor de XHTML para gerar páginas de HTML5 e caso esse programa não seja capaz de produzir o doctype curto `<!DOCTYPE html>`, você poderá com o seu programa obsoleto gerar o doctype `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` e a página não será processada em *quirks mode* ou *almost standards mode*. Abaixo as explicações do porquê.

Tem muitos conceitos errados na pergunta e algumas coisas devem ser esclarecidas. Não é um ataque e desqualificação, é só uma necessidade de tornar todos esses conceitos padronizados entre todos aqueles que discutem o assunto.

#### ...Eu li o artigo na WHATWG...

Inicialmente o que é chama de artigo na pergunta é a especificação do padrão HTML5. Atualmente [duas entidades trabalham e regulam esse padrão](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/7753).

- [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) e [WHATWG](https://whatwg.org/) trabalham juntos em HTML e DOM, nos repositórios WHATWG, para produzir um padrão vivo e rascunhos de recomendação/revisão instantâneos
- WHATWG mantém os Padrões Vivos HTML e DOM
- O W3C facilita o trabalho da comunidade diretamente nos repositórios do WHATWG (ligando comunidades, desenvolvendo casos de uso, arquivando problemas, escrevendo testes, mediando a resolução de problemas)
- O W3C interrompe a publicação independente de uma lista designada de especificações relacionadas a HTML e DOM e, em vez disso, trabalhará para levar os rascunhos de revisão do WHATWG às recomendações do W3C

Segundo o W3C uma recomendação é:

> #### [O que significa "padrão da Web"? O que é uma "Recomendação"?](https://www.w3.org/standards/faq#std)
>
> O W3C publica documentos que definem as tecnologias da Web. Esses documentos
> seguem um processo projetado para promover consenso, equidade,
> responsabilidade pública e qualidade. Ao final desse processo, o W3C
> publica as Recomendações , que são consideradas padrões da Web.

Segundo o WHATWG o Padrão Vivo HTML5 é:

> #### [O que significa “Padrão Vivo”?](https://whatwg.org/faq#living-standard)
>
> Os padrões WHATWG são descritos como
> Padrões Vivos. Isso significa que são padrões que são atualizados
> continuamente à medida que recebem feedback, seja de desenvolvedores
> da Web, fornecedores de navegadores, fornecedores de ferramentas ou de
> qualquer outra parte interessada. Isso também significa que novos
> recursos são adicionados a eles ao longo do tempo, a uma taxa
> destinada a manter o padrão um pouco à frente das implementações, mas
> não tão à frente que as implementações desistam.
>
> Apesar da manutenção contínua, ou talvez devêssemos dizer como parte da
> manutenção contínua, um esforço significativo é feito para fazer o
> padrão e as implementações convergirem — as partes do padrão que são
> maduras e estáveis ​​não são alteradas a torto e a direito. Manutenção
> significa que os dias em que o padrão é derrubado da montanha e
> permanecem bloqueados para sempre, mesmo que todos os navegadores
> façam outra coisa, ou mesmo que o padrão tenha deixado algum detalhe
> de fora e todos os navegadores discordem sobre como implementá-lo,
> desapareceram. Em vez disso, agora nos certificamos de atualizar o
> padrão para ser detalhado o suficiente para que todas as
> implementações (não apenas navegadores, é claro) possam fazer a mesma
> coisa. Em vez de ignorar o que os navegadores fazem, corrigimos o
> padrão para corresponder ao que os navegadores fazem. Em vez de deixar
> o padrão ambíguo, fixamos o padrão para definir como as coisas
> funcionam.

#### ...`<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` antigo que era utilizado antes da versão curta `<!DOCTYPE html>`...

O `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` nunca foi utilizado, veja a [Lista de DTD Válidos](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) e [Qual é a função da meta tag "X-UA-Compatible" dentro do HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209599/137387).

#### ...Atualmente os navegadores com ou sem o DOCTYPE mais recente já vão saber como renderizar a página...

Segundo o [glossário do MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Doctype):

> No HTML, o *doctype* é a introdução `<!DOCTYPE html>` encontrada no topo
> de todos os documentos. Seu único propósito é evitar que o browser
> mude para os chamados [**“quirks mode”**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) quando renderizar um documento;
> isto é, o `<!DOCTYPE html>` *doctype* garante que o browser faça um
> esforço na tentativa de seguir as especificações relevantes, em vez de
> usar um modo de renderização diferente e que seja incompatível com
> algumas especificações.

No final da década de 1990 as páginas de internet eram majoritariamente escritas em duas versões, uma para o [Netscape Navigator](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator) e outra para o [Microsoft Internet Explorer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer). Esse período foi conhecido como [A Guerra dos Navegadores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerra_dos_navegadores).
Quando os padrões web foram criados pelo W3C, navegadores não puderam começar a usá-los imediatamente, pois isto iria quebrar a maior parte dos sites existentes na web.
Os navegadores fazem a análise do doctype (ou "*doctype sniffing*") para decidir qual o engine para processar documentos HTML.

Hoje existem três modos usados pelos engines de layout nos navegadores web:

- [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode): o layout emula o comportamento não padrão do Netscape Navigator 4 e do Internet Explorer 5.
- [almost standards mode](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/almost_standards_mode): Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Edge, Opera (desde 7.5), IE8, IE9, IE10 e IE11 também possuem um modo conhecido como "Almost Standards Mode", que implementa o dimensionamento vertical das células da tabela tradicionalmente e não de acordo com a especificação CSS2. Mac IE 5, Windows IE 6 e 7, Opera anterior a 7.5 e Konqueror não precisavam de um almost standards mode, porque eles não implementavam o dimensionamento vertical das células da tabela de acordo com a especificação CSS2 em seus respectivos standard modes. Na verdade, seus standard mode estão mais próximos do almost standards mode do que do standard mode dos navegadores atuais.
- full standards mode: modo de padrão fornecer suporte para HTML e CSS padronizados nos principais navegadores da web atuais.

Então caso de documento HTML5 você deve iniciar todos os seus documentos HTML com `<!DOCTYPE html>` como a primeira coisa na fonte para evitar *quirks mode* e *almost standards mode*.

#### ...Onde colocar o `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">`?...

**Em lugar nenhum!**

Se analisar a documentação:

> #### [13.1.1 O DOCTYPE](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype)
>
> Um DOCTYPE é um preâmbulo obrigatório.
> Um DOCTYPE deve consistir nos seguintes componentes, nesta ordem:
>
> 1. Uma string que é uma correspondência ASCII sem distinção entre maiúsculas e 2. minúsculas para a string " <!DOCTYPE".
> 2. Um ou mais espaços em branco ASCII .
> 3. Uma string que é uma correspondência ASCII sem distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas para a string " html".
> 4. Opcionalmente, uma string legada DOCTYPE .
> 5. Zero ou mais espaços em branco ASCII .
> 6. Um caractere de sinal de maior que U+003E (>).
>
> Para fins de geradores de HTML que não podem gerar marcação HTML com o
> DOCTYPE curto `<!DOCTYPE html>`, uma string legada DOCTYPE pode ser
> inserida no DOCTYPE (na posição definida acima). Esta string deve
> consistir em:
>
> 1. Um ou mais espaços em branco ASCII .
> 2. Uma string que é uma correspondência ASCII sem distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas para a string " SYSTEM".
> 3. Um ou mais espaços em branco ASCII .
> 4. Um caractere de aspas U+0022 ou APOSTROFO U+0027 (as aspas ).
> 5. A string literal " about:legacy-compat".
> 6. Um caractere correspondente U+0022 ASPAS ou U+0027 APOSTROFO (ou seja, o mesmo caractere da etapa anterior rotulada como aspas ).
> 7. Em outras palavras, ou , sem distinção entre
>    maiúsculas e minúsculas, exceto para a parte entre aspas simples ou
>    duplas.
>
> *A string legada DOCTYPE não deve ser usada, a menos que o documento seja gerado a partir de um sistema que não pode produzir a string mais
> curta.*

Ou seja caso você estiver utilizando um programa editor de XHTML para gerar páginas de HTML5 e caso esse programa não seja capaz de produzir o doctype curta `<!DOCTYPE html>` você poderá com o seu programa obsoleto gerar a o doctype `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` e a página não será processada em *quirks mode* ou *almost standards mode*.