# As tags que não possuem fechamento tem alguma finalidade em especial?

Tags: html, característica-linguagem

Muitas vezes eu me deparo com *tags* HTML sendo usada de duas formas.

Primeira forma:

```
<title>Stackoverflow</title>
```

Segunda forma:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Repare que na *tag* `title` houve o fechamento `</>` e na *tag* `meta` não houve o fechamento.

Em situações, em que há *tags* que possui fechamento e outras que não possui fechamento eu tenho a seguinte dúvida.

## Dúvida

As *tags* que não possui fechamentos tem alguma finalidade em especial? Elas são só *tags* que serve para configurar algo na pagina? Assim como a *tag* `meta` que define a codificação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, elas são apenas *tags* que não precisam ser fechadas, ou seja, não tem conteúdo que ela controla. Pode ser um `<meta>`  ou pode ser um `<br>`. A *tag* existe por si própria. Ela pode ter atributos, como demonstrado na pergunta. Uma `<img>` tem nas propriedades tudo o que ela precisa, o fechamento só seria necessário para indicar que o conteúdo acabou, mas não nenhum conteúdo vinculado à *tag* a não ser ela própria.

A maioria das *tags* simples (sem fechamento) renderizam alguma coisa mesmo não tendo um conteúdo associado. O conteúdo pode estar determinado em um atributo, caso da `<img>` onde ela já é a própria imagem ou `<br>` que só renderiza um "pular linha".

Já citei dois casos que não são para configuração de nada. Outras:

- `area`
- `base`
- `col`
- `command`
- `embed`
- `hr`
- `input`
- `keygen`
- `link`
- `menuitem`
- `param`
- `source`
- `track`
- `wbr`

Esqueci algum? Talvez versões novas tenham outros exemplos.

*Tags* que possuem terminadores precisam ter um conteúdo associado, que pode ser um texto ou uma *tag* ou um conjunto de *tags*. Ter o fechamento é algo que só é necessário quando existe algo que precise ser determinado que terminou o que precisava ser descrito.

Pensa no `;` e o `{ }` em boa parte das linguagens de programação. Por que existe algo que só indica o fim e algo que indica início e fim? É o mesmo motivo, um elemento indica algo único e outro indica algo composto, que precisa de um indicador que a composição terminou.

O mesmo poderia ser dito das aspas. Por que não precisa de um terminador em um número ou um `true`? Porque existe uma regra que identifica sua composição, ao contrário da *string* que precisa de algo que determina seu início e fim. É só por causa disto que existe o terminador ou falta dele.

Pra que fazer isto?

```
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
```

Se isto basta?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Meta.html).

Relacionado: [O certo é <br> ou <br/> ou <br />?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46370/101).

Comment: Então as tags que tem fechamento, geralmente tem um conteúdo que sera renderizado pelo navegador e exibido ao usuário, seria isso?

Comment: Não exatamente, precisa ter um conteúdo associado, que pode ser um texto ou uma *tag* ou um conjunto de *tags*. Se fosse tudo o que será renderizado a `<img>` teria que ter fechamento, mas não tem, porque o que ela renderiza não tem nada associado a ela, ela já é a própria imagem. Ter o fechamento é algo que só é necessário quando existe algo que precise ser determinado que terminou o que precisava ser descrito. Pensa no `;` e o `{ } ` em boa parte das linguagens de programação. Por que existe algo que indica início e fim e algo que só indica o fim? É o mesmo motivo. Ser algo único ou composto

Comment: @bigown esse seu comentário complementar já é praticamente outra resposta! Este exemplo dado é tão explicativo, não acha que seria interessante como parte da resposta?

Comment: @diegofm feito.