# <br> está obsoleto?

Tags: css, html5, aplicação-web, webdesign

Com o advento dos layouts responsivos/adaptativo/fluidos está cada vez menos comum o uso do `<br>` para definir espaçamentos no layout. O uso dele não é recomendado nesses layouts modernos ou é só uma questão de prática de programação de separar a responsabilidade para o CSS?

Comment: Mas `<br>` é um elemento que define quebra de linhas em **textos**, nem deveria ser utilizado para definir o *layout*.

Comment: Acredito que seja pelo fato de com espaçamentos você conseguir ter mais dinamismo pois com o br os espaços vão sendo automático já com espaçamento você pode definir.

Comment: Uma observação, é que após a reformulação do HTML 4.01 em (x)HTML 1.0 pela W3C - onde adequa-se a sintaxe para XML - não é necessário a inclusão de uma tag de fechamento, você deve sinalizar a própria tag: `<br />`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isto era comum antigamente, era a forma de estruturação, era a base de Table e BR .

Comment: Eu acho que Br tá em voga sobretudo aqui em Portugal, zoando so, mas br e bom pra editar textos e não fazer o layout em si na minha opinião

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Não, não está obsoleto.

O elemento `<br>` define uma nova quebra de linha em textos, não em *layouts*. Semanticamente falando, tal elemento jamais deveria ser utilizado como estrutura do *layout*. Basta ver o que a [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) / [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) diz:

> *`<br>` elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses.*

Ou seja, ele ainda existe, não está nem perto de ser obsoleto e deve ser utilizado para o que foi feito: quebras de linhas em textos.

Documentação da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) também diz:

> O elemento HTML quebra-de-linha `<br>` produz uma quebra de linha **em um texto** (carriage-return). É útil para escrever poemas ou um endereço, onde a divisão de linha é significante.

Para qualquer organização do *layout*, o recomendado será buscar outro elemento que foi especificado para tal (por exemplo, se `<br>` define a quebra de linha entre dois elementos *inline*, será melhor utilizar elementos *block*) ou utilizar o CSS para a formatação.

Comment: Só lembrando que quebrar linhas em texto não é paragrafação.

Comment: Carriage Return? Que preconceito!!!! Por que não Line Feed?

Comment: @JéfBueno
o efeito prático é o da soma de ambos. A diferença deles fica mais evidente em impressoras com mecânica similar às matriciais ou de margarida. Se você manda um CR e mais texto, o cabeçote volta pro começo e escreve por cima da linha já existente. Se manda um LF no meio da linha, o texto vai sair na linha seguinte mas... do meio em diante. Por isso o uso do CRLF se consolidou. As aplicações é que não "imitaram" em tela o comportamento.

Comment: @Bacco era só uma brincadeira hehehe. De qualquer forma, você poderia comentar isso na minha pergunta sobre estes caras, né? Cabe certinho no contexto.

Comment: @JéfBueno ah sim, só aproveitei o gancho pra deixar um pouco de história :) - Pesquisei um pouco, vi que praticamente ninguem fala nisso. Preciso produzir uma imagem ilustrando.

Comment: @Bacco sim, isso é realmente muito interessante.

Comment: A pergunta foi bem objetiva. Se está obsoleto, está sim, porque antigamente era comum usar o br para espaçamento em layouts, e hoje em dia não há necessidade mais .
Aqui a questão não gira em torno de fazer pesquisinha e dar resposta editadinha e formatadinha, estamos tratando de experiência da evolução das práticas do código, etc. De ter vivido outros momentos e conhecido outras tendencias na marcação html e não na boa prática da acentuação .

Comment: @DavidAugustus se discorda da resposta e tem algo a acrescentar, pode responder a pergunta também. É assim que funciona a comunidade: cada um colabora um pouco e todos aprendem. Eu discordo completamente do que disse e não vejo o que mudar na minha resposta.

Comment: Só vamos acreditar no futuro da World Wide Web, uma vez que nos afastamos dos padrões implementados pelos seus idealizadores, e devemos nos adequar ao padrão do codificador ortográfico. Mas se um dia voltarmos a uma marcação sólida, confiável e que trabalhe dados em escala, teriamos o uso do XML e do JSON para receber dados para a página como arquitetura REST. Aí nesse caso não poderia usar o <br> porque não é compatível a quebra de linha com a formatação do texto. Então, desta forma, para quem desenvolve só "HyperMedia" não faz diferença. O navegador vai entender o BR onde for.

Comment: @DavidAugustus ainda não entendi seu ponto de vista. Poderia elaborar uma resposta apresentando-a de forma completa?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Já vi em alguns códigos usarem `<br/>` em vez de `<br>`, ambos são equivalentes?

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser Sobre isso você pode ler em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46370/5878

Answer (score 1):

Como vc pode ver no exemplo com o uso de **br** vc não tem controle sobre o espaçamento dos elementos como vc tem utilizando **div** por exemplo, que dá facilmente para vc controlar pelo **CSS**.

```css
div {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Utilizando br</h3>
Texto qualquer
<br>
<br>
Outro texto qualquer
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<h3>Utilizando div
<div>Texto qualquer</div>
<div>Outro texto qualquer</div>
```