# Imagem não cobre a tela inteira?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um banner mais ele não está cobrindo a tela inteira igual a imagem a abaixo dele, o banner fica com umas partes branca em torno dele.

Obs.: Nesse mesmo banner estou tentando fazer o efeito paralax, e não está funcionando se alguém puder me dar uma dica do que fazer, agradeço.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#brand-image{
 height: 100px;
 float: center;
}
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 15px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;  
}
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
 margin-top: -20px;
}
/***************Corpo**********/
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-image: url(img/fundo.jpg);
}

.wrapper{
    height: 50%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    perspective: -10px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.adesao{
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
    min-width: 700px;
    transform-style: inherit;
}
.adesao::before{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
}
.txt_adesao{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px o;

    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.txt_vejamais{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 20px o;

    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;

}
.bg1::before{
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/21wBdiC.jpg);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap-4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
 <title>Formandos de Mecatrônica</title>

 <nav class="nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
       <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" />
     </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
         <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Buffet</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Local</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Loja</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <main class="wrapper">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <section class="adesao bg1">
     <p class="txt_adesao">Faça sua ADESAO ONLINE </p>
     <p class="txt_vejamais">Veja Mais</p>
    </section>
   </a>
  </main>
 </div>
 </br>
 <div>
  <img src="https://images7.alphacoders.com/671/671281.jpg" width="100%">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sério mesmo que você quer colocar uma imagem de **30MB** no seu projeto? E esse `nav` no `<head>`?

Comment: Não essa imagem eu coloquei de exemplo, peguei aleatoriamente no google, só para efeito de comparação, essa imagem ela pega a tela inteira, enquanto o banner não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema das margens são os *paddings* `left` e `right` da classe `.container-fluid`. Você pode eliminá-las colocando a classe `px-0`:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
```

A classe `px-0` elimina os paddings laterais.

O espaçamento abaixo se dá por conta do `<br>`, que não deveria estar ali (**[veja nesta resposta o correto uso do `<br>`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305166/8063)**)

Existe também um erro no CSS:

```
padding: 20px o; /* usando a letra "o" em vez do número 0 */
```

Outro problema é o `<nav>` dentro da tag `<head>`, quando deveria estar no `<body>`.

> Outro erro é o `float: center;`. Não existe o valor `center` para
>   `float`. Evite usar `float`, ainda mais com Bootstrap.

Para fazer o efeito parallax, coloque a propriedade `background-attachment: fixed;` na classe `.bg1::before{`. Isso irá *fixar* a imagem de fundo fazendo o efeito funcionar:

```
.bg1::before{
   max-width: 100%;
   background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/21wBdiC.jpg);
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**Exemplo:** (substituí a imagem pesada por outra)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#brand-image{
height: 100px;
float: center;
}
.nav {
position: fixed;
padding-top: 15px;
top: 0;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;  
}
.navbar-brand {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
display: block;
margin-top: -20px;
}
/***************Corpo**********/
body, html{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body{
background-image: url(img/fundo.jpg);
}

.wrapper{
height: 50%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
perspective: -10px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.adesao{
position: relative;
height: 450px;
min-width: 700px;
transform-style: inherit;
 }
 .adesao::before{
content: " ";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: -1;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
}
.txt_adesao{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px 0;

color: white;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
.txt_vejamais{
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
left: 45%;
width: 10%;
padding: 20px o;

color: white;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;

}
.bg1::before{
   max-width: 100%;
   background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/21wBdiC.jpg);
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
       <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" />
     </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
         <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Buffet</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Local</a>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Loja</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
   <div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <main class="wrapper">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <section class="adesao bg1">
     <p class="txt_adesao">Faça sua ADESAO ONLINE </p>
     <p class="txt_vejamais">Veja Mais</p>
    </section>
   </a>
  </main>
 </div>
 </br>
 <div>
  <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="100%">
 </div>
```