# Salvar input de formulário html em csv

Tags: php, html, csv

Criei um formulário em html onde o usuário digita o nome, e-mail, telefone, porém preciso resgatar estes "cadastros" em csv pra futuro disparo de e-mail.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda em como alimentar este csv com inputs?

```
<form>  
  <input type="text" name="Nome" value="Nome"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="mail" name="mail" value="e-mail"><br>
  <br>
  Sexo<br>
  Masculino
  <input type="checkbox" name="homem" value="masculino"><br>
  Feminino
  <input type="checkbox" name="mulher" value="feminino"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Todos os artigos que encontrei, ensinavam a repassar para um arquivo php. Minha dúvida é, input de formulário só pode ir pra php? Se sim, teria que criar uma função dentro do php pra alimentar o arquivo csv?

Acabei de me formar em html/css e pyton, não tenho muito conhecimento em php ou outras linguagens.

Desde já muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa corrigir seu HTML. Veja algumas alterações que fiz no action, method do form, no tipo de campo de e-mail e como lidar com checkboxes:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">  
  <input type="text" name="nome" value="Nome"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="mail" value="E-mail"><br>
  <br>
  Sexo<br>
  Masculino
  <input type="checkbox" name="sexo[]" value="Masculino"><br>
  Feminino
  <input type="checkbox" name="sexo[]" value="Feminino"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

E no arquivo save.php:

```
<?php
    //Caminho e nome do arquivo (se colocar só o nome do arquivo, ele deve estar na mesma pasta do PHP)
    $file = "lista.csv";
    //Carregar o arquivo existente
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    //Criar (usando informações fornecidas pelo formulário HTML) e adicionar nova linha ao conteúdo já existente
    $current .= $_POST['nome'].', '.$_POST['mail'].', '.$_POST['sexo'][0]."\n";
    //Adicionar conteúdo todo ao arquivo
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Crie o arquivo lista.csv na mesma pasta desse HTML e PHP para que ele funcione do jeito que está nesse código. Esse código irá pegar o conteúdo existente do lista.csv e adicionar uma nova linha com o conteúdo do formulário.

Espero ter resolvido seu problema.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de carregar todo o conteúdo do arquivo em memória só para adicionar uma linha ao final?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, assim como você possivelmente fazia em Python você necessitará ter o PHP processando a sua requisição e salvando as informações no arquivo.

Possuindo um *array* com os dados que você deseja salvar no arquivo CSV você poderá utilizar a função [`fputcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php). Para tal, você deverá abrir o arquivo em modo de escrita sem substituição do conteúdo.

```php
$data = ["foo", "bar", 1];

$handler = fopen("arquivo.csv", "a");

if (false !== $handler) {
    fputcsv($handler, $data);
    fclose($handler);
}
```

Diferente da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342202/5878), que se baseou `file_get_contents` e `file_put_contents`, esta forma não carrega o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo em memória apenas para adicionar uma nova linha ao final, o que é uma grande melhoria em questão de performance e economia de recursos.

**Considerações sobre o HTML**

1. Seja consistente quanto aos nomes dos campos. Evite nomear um campo iniciando com letra maiúscula e outro com minúscula; isso facilitará a manutenção.
2. O tipo `type="mail"` não existe. O correto é `type="email"`.
3. Não utilize `<br>` para definir layout. Veja sobre isso em [<br> está obsoleto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305160/5878)
4. Não utilize `checkbox` para solicitar algo que demande resposta única. Sem entrar no mérito de gêneros, você pode ser apenas homem ou mulher, não ambos. Use `radio` ou `select` no lugar.
5. Se utilizar `radio` o nome do campo deve ser igual para todas as opções. De forma equivalente, no `checkbox` o nome também deve ser igual, seguido de `[]` para indicar que será possível múltiplos valores.
6. Não use o atributo `value` do `<input>` para definir uma mensagem padrão no campo, use `placeholder` ao invés disso.