# Como eu posso definir quebras de linha entre elementos de um layout?

Tags: html, css

Estou estuando CSS e HTML e uma das dúvidas que sempre me surgem é na maneira que devo definir a quebra de linha entre elementos de um layout.

Por exemplo:

```html
<p>Nome</p>
<input type="text" name="nome">
<button name="salvar">Salvar</button>
```

No código acima eu posso usar a tag `<br>` para quebrar a linha entre o botão e o campo, veja o resultado:

```html
<p>Nome</p>
<input type="text" name="nome">
<br>
<button name="salvar">Salvar</button>
```

No entanto, me parece mais sensato usar a tag `<br>` para quebrar linha de textos e não de elementos. Porém, eu não sei como eu posso fazer isso usando CSS.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de ter essas dúvidas esclarecidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Como eu posso definir quebras de linha entre elementos de um layout sem usar a tag `<br>`?
2. Eu posso usar o `<br>`? Caso não, quais seriam os motivos de não
   usa-lo para quebra de linha?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma dica que te dou seria dar uma lida nessa pergunta para entender bem o que é o `<br>` etc [<br> está obsoleto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305160/br-est%C3%A1-obsoleto)

Mas resumindo `<br>` é para quebrar linhas de texto, ou separa em linhas elementos que são do tipo *inline*. Então como no seu exemplo o `input` e `button` são elementos do tipo *inline* não há problema em usar o `br` para quebrar a linha entre eles. Aqui vc pode consultar a lista dos elementos HTML que são *inline* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente

Já os elementos do tipo *block* quebram a linha automaticamente, pois eles têm 100% de largura e nada fica ao lado deles na mesma linha. É o caso para elementos como `div`, `p` ou `h1` por exemplo. Lista de elementos HTML do tipo *block* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Mas nada impede que vc pegue um elemento que por default é *inline* ,como uma `label`, e coloque nela `display:block`, isso vai fazer com que o elemento que venha ao lado dessa `label` passe para linha de baixo, já que agora a `label` vai passar a ocupar 100% da largura por estar com `display:block`.

Um exemplo de como um elemento do tipo *block* pode ficar *inline* e como um elemento do tipo *inline* pode ficar *block*.

```css
h2 {
    display: inline;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>duas h2 com display:inline</p>
<h2>h2 na mesma linha</h2>
<h2>que outro h2</h2>
<hr>
<p>agora duas label com display:block</p>
<label for="">uma label na linha 1</label>
<label for="">uma label na linha 2</label>
```

---

Uma dica que te dou é ler sobre o **Box Model** para entender bem como um elemento HTML é constituído, ***como ele ocupa o próprio espaço e o espaço ao seu redor***: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

Entendendo o **Box Model** vc vai entender melhor quando e porque mudar o tipo de `display` de um elemento, assim esse elemento pode passar a aceita por exemplo `margin-top`, e outras propriedades que seriam de um elemento *block* e um elemento *inline*.

Comment: Eu "ia" reformular minha resposta. Mas você já retratou tudo que precisava...