# Problema ao exibir imagens e ícone em site

Tags: html

Boa tarde, estou com um problema em relação as imagens.

1. imagem de ícone da pagina
   adicione o caminho e a imagem há pasta do projeto, porém a mesma não está sendo exibida, isso pode ser algum problema de proporção da imagem?
2. imagem de exibição final
   adicionei uma imagem qualquer ao final do código, porém ela não está sendo exibida na pagina poderiam me ajudar nesse erro de código que cometi?
   quero entender o que estou fazendo de errado. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   <

```css
h1 {font-size:80px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 165, 0);
    color: #fafffa;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
    
}
h2 {font-size:50px;
    font-family: "arial", sans-serif;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset"utf-8">
        <title>Evento Meeting empresa</title>

        <link rel="icon" href"logogarrah.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bio.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>MEETING 19/07</h1>

        <h2>Regras do participante</h2>

        <p>participantes devem se inscrever para participar do evento</p>
        
        
        
        <h2>Local do evento</h2>

        <p>butantã</p>
        
        <ing src="logogarrah.png" alt="logo garrah"></ing>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ERRADO:

```
<link rel="icon" href"logogarrah.png">
```

> CORRETO:

```
<link rel="icon" href="logogarrah.png">
```

> ERRADO:

```
<ing src="logogarrah.png" alt="logo garrah"></ing>
```

> CORRETO:

```
<img src="logogarrah.png" alt="logo garrah" />
```

Comment: Tag img não tem fechamento jovem

Comment: Verdade, fui no embalo do erro :)

Comment: HTML5 também não tem `/>`

Comment: Estranho, olhei lá no site da Mozilla e lá tem. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Vale a pena da uma lida https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46370/o-certo-%C3%A9-br-ou-br-ou-br